# How to work around the unavailibilty of passing by reference in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, pass-by-reference

My problem is around the fact that I cannot pass by reference in Ruby.
I have two functions `searching` and `get_title_ids`.

I have two arrays in `searching`

(1) title  (2) href
which needs to be *updated*.

```
def searching
    title = []
    href = []
    (0..20).step(10) do |i|
        prev= title.length
        title, href = get_title_ids(i, title, href) ## <<-- Should have just done "get_title_ids(i, title, href)"
        ## something which on next iteration will increase the ids and hrefs
        puts "\nthe title lenght is #{title.length} and href length is #{href.length}\n"
        assert_operator prev,:<,title.length,"After scrolling to bottom no new jobs are getting added" 
    end
end

def get_title_ids (start_from=0, title=[], href=[])
    #Part of code which can store all links and titles of jobs displayed
    (start_from..(titles.length-1)).each do |i|
            unless titles[i].text.chomp
                title << titles[i].text.chomp
                href << titles[i].attribute("href")
            end     
        end
    end
    return [title, href] ### <<---- this is what messed it up
end
```

The problem is I am unable to `push` *new* elements into the arrays `title` and `href` that have been defined in `searching`.

Each time I call `get_title_ids` i do not want to gather data that I had previously gathered(hence the start_form).

My problem is not memory but time. So i am not too concerned about the data being duplicated when I call the `get_title_ids`  function as compared to the fact that I have to waste time scrapping data that I already scrapped in the previous for loop.

So does any one know how to hack the pass by reference in Ruby.

### EDIT

SO from reading the questions below turns out I dint need to perform the `return` from `get_title_ids`. And then it all worked.

Comment: Even if a reference type object is passed by value, it is still _referring_ to the same object in memory.

Comment: Great! So that saves me from memory duplication :), but how do I `push` elements in the array passed by value/reference

Comment: I think here's problem not because of reference but because you don't know how to use iterators.

Comment: @megas, I think the iterators were fine. It was the `return` that screwed things up. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in ruby are most certainly passed by reference (well, technically, they are passed by value, but that value is a pointer to the array). Observe:

```
def push_new ary
  ary << 'new element'
end

a = ['first element']
push_new a
a # => ["first element", "new element"]
```

Comment: That is what I have done, but the length remains the same, so with your example. my `a` now is `a=> ["new element"]`

Comment: What do you mean, "length remains the same"? Do you need it to be the same? How are you adding new elements then, by discarding old ones?

Comment: Well i dint want the old ones to be discarded, but they were. I guess the problem was the last `return`, which caused all the problems. Thanks for your help. Will mark your solution as the answer as you were the first to reply apart from pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No, everything is passed and assigned by value in Ruby. Objects are not values. All values are references.

Comment: Did you read my answer carefully? :) Also, not all values are references.

Answer (score 1):

Even if a reference type object is passed by value, it is still referring to the same object in memory. If this were not the case then the example below would not work.

example:

```
> def searching
>   title = []
>   href = []
>   test(title, href)
>   puts "Title: #{title.inspect} Href: #{href.inspect}"
> end

> def test(title, href)
>   title << "title1"
>   title << "title2"
>   href << "www.title1.com"
>   href << "www.title2.com"
> end

> searching

Title: ["title1", "title2"] Href: ["www.title1.com", "www.title2.com"]
```